# Where to find official list of UIDeviceFamily values?

Tags: ios, macos, apple-watch, tvos

When creating an app for iOS, tvOS, Apple Watch, or macOS you are expected to fill out the `UIDeviceFamily` in the info.plist file

I've found [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW11) claiming that a UIDeviceFamily value of `1` means "iOS" and a UIDeviceFamily values of `2` means "iPad". However beyond these two values, I can't find any ***official*** source for the *other* possible values. I've found a handful of StackOverflow posts, or Apple developer forum posts, where someone makes a mention of a particular value, but nothing definitive. Like `4` seems to be Apple Watch and `3` is tvOS, I think? But what's `5`? Is there a `5`? And what's the number of "macOS"?

I'm trying to find the **official** source for these values, so that if there are any issues I can refer back to it.

Comment: so bad Apple don't keep the documentation updated

Answer (score 0):

This [Twitter post](https://twitter.com/felipecn/status/890759859209109504) said `5` is Homepod